# How to identify changed property values when comparing two nested data structures?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, difference

I'm working on a TypeScript project where I need to compare two objects with potentially nested structures and identify the fields that have changed between them. For instance, consider an old object oldObject with fields like name, age, city, friends (an array), and possibly nested objects within. Now, I have a new object newObject with the same structure, but with potentially updated values for some fields.

Here's an example:

```
const oldObject = { name: 'John', age: 30, city: 'New York', friends: ['ali', 'qasim'], def: { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 } };
const newObject = { name: 'John', age: 35, city: 'New York', friends: ['ali', 'haider'] };
```

In this scenario, I need to be able to identify and extract the changed fields between oldObject and newObject, along with their new values, retaining the nested structure.

I've attempted a comparison function, but it's not correctly handling nested structures and arrays. How can I implement a solution in TypeScript that accurately identifies the changed fields while preserving the nested structure of the objects?

- I'm looking for a TypeScript function or approach that can accurately identify changed fields between two objects with nested structures.
- The function should correctly handle nested objects and arrays, identifying changes within them.
- The solution should be efficient and scalable for objects of varying sizes and complexities.
- Any insights or improvements on the provided sample function would be greatly appreciated.
- Clear explanations and examples would be helpful for better understanding and implementation.

Comment: You've just listed some requirements here. What have you tried so far? Which problems are you facing? Also, you say *I have a new object newObject with the same structure* but in your example the structure has certainly changed. Property `def` does no longer exist in `newObject`.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at doing this yourself? If so, what issues have you encountered? If not, what do you expect to see here, a full solution or a suggestion to get started?

Comment: "*I've attempted a comparison function*" - please show us the code of that attempt and an example where it doesn't work (and the expected output).

Comment: @TAYYAB-IT ... regarding any of the other answers, are there any questions left?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

To accurately identify and compare changed fields in TypeScript objects with nested structures, you can utilize a recursive approach. Here's how you can implement a function to achieve this:

```js
  function findChangedFields(oldObj: any, newObj: any): { old: any, new: any } {
const changedFields: { old: any, new: any } = { old: {}, new: {} };

for (const key in oldObj) {
    if (oldObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (!newObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            changedFields.old[key] = oldObj[key];
            changedFields.new[key] = undefined; // Field does not exist in new object
        } else if (Array.isArray(oldObj[key]) && Array.isArray(newObj[key])) {
            if (JSON.stringify(oldObj[key]) !== JSON.stringify(newObj[key])) {
                changedFields.old[key] = oldObj[key];
                changedFields.new[key] = newObj[key];
            }
        } else if (typeof oldObj[key] === 'object' && typeof newObj[key] === 'object') {
            const nestedChanges = findChangedFields(oldObj[key], newObj[key]);
            if (Object.keys(nestedChanges.old).length > 0 || Object.keys(nestedChanges.new).length > 0) {
                changedFields.old[key] = nestedChanges.old;
                changedFields.new[key] = nestedChanges.new;
            }
        } else {
            if (oldObj[key] !== newObj[key]) {
                changedFields.old[key] = oldObj[key];
                changedFields.new[key] = newObj[key];
            }
        }
    }
}

// Check for new keys in newObj
for (const key in newObj) {
    if (newObj.hasOwnProperty(key) && !oldObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        changedFields.old[key] = undefined; // Field does not exist in old object
        changedFields.new[key] = newObj[key];
    }
}

return changedFields;
}

// Example usage:
const oldObject = { name: 'John', age: 30, city: 'New York', friends: ['ali', 'qasim'], def: { 'a': 1, 'b': 3 }, ng: { a: { d: 1 } } };
const newObject = { name: 'John', age: 35, city: 'New York', friends: ['ali', 'haider'], def: {}, ng: { a: {} } };

const changedFields = findChangedFields(oldObject, newObject);
console.log(changedFields);
```

This function recursively traverses through the objects and arrays to compare their elements. If a difference is found, it records the changed field along with its new value in the changedFields object.

You can test this function with your sample objects oldObject and newObject to see the changed fields along with their new values.

Comment: You had an answer lined up for this question already? Or is this AI-generated?  The former is fine (but the answer tickles my AI-detector neurons), the latter is a violation of the rules here.

Comment: On top, the provided code throws an exception, thus it can not even prove whether the approach is viable. I myself doubt any implementation which at any part uses `JSON.stringify` for object comparison. Such code is error prone for it always fails with objects which are structurally identical but at just one property already have a different key insertion order. This and the first two introduction sentences reveal the deep learning model. A sane human mind, which cares for the correctness of answer and example code would neither come up with such crap nor present it that self confidently.

Comment: @TAYYAB-IT ... the implementation, after having fixed the code exception cause, wrongly identifies property value changes for two identical structures like ... `const oldObject = { friends: [{ foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR' }, { baz: 'BAZ', biz: 'BIZ' }] };` and `const newObject = { friends: [{ foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR' }, { biz: 'BIZ', baz: 'BAZ' }] };`

Answer (score 1):

A feasibly approach for tackling the OP's problem could be based on serializing any given data-structure into a keypath based map/index.

When comparing and diffing two data-structures one would first create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) based serialized variant of each structure.

Then one easily can create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instance of each created map which holds just the keypath strings of each related, serialized data-structure.

By making use of the new `Set` methods [`intersection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/intersection) and [`difference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/difference) (utilizing the js-core implementations of the latter two) one retrieves specific sets of keypath strings, like overlapping keypaths and keypaths which are unique to each data-structure.

Having reached that point it is pretty easy to create a `diff` object from all the created maps and sets, which is ...

- computing a `changed` diff-entry which points out different values at one and the same keypath.
- creating a `deleted` diff-entry which features keypath based key-value pairs that are unique to the provided ***recent data object***.
- creating an `added` diff-entry which features keypath based key-value pairs that are unique to the provided ***current data object***.

```js
const oldObject = {
  name: 'John', age: 30,
  friends: ['ali', 'qasim', { foo: 'Foo', 'foo bar': { baz: 'Baz', biz: 'Biz' } }],
};
const newObject = {
  name: 'John', age: 35, city: 'New York',
  friends: ['ali', 'haider', { 'foo bar': { baz: 'BAZ'}, foo: 'Foo' }],
};

const diff = diffDataValuesByKeypath(oldObject, newObject);

console.log({ oldObject, newObject, diff });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/3.36.0/minified.js"></script>

<script>
function concatKeypath(keypath, key) {

  // - test for a key which can be used with dot chaining.
  // - see ... [https://regex101.com/r/tew8gr/1]
  return (/^[_$\p{L}][_$\p{L}\p{N}]*$/u).test(key)

    // - concat a dot chained key.
    ? (!!keypath && `${ keypath }.${ key }` || key)

    // - concat a quoted key with square bracket notation.
    : `${ keypath }["${ key }"]`;
}

function mapDataStructure(value, keypath = '', map = new Map) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    value
      .forEach((item, idx) =>

        mapDataStructure(item, `${ keypath }[${ idx }]`, map)
      );
  } else if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
    Object
      .entries(value)
      .forEach(([key, val]) =>

        mapDataStructure(val, concatKeypath(keypath, key), map)
      );
  } else {
    map.set(keypath, value);
  }
  return map;
}

function diffDataValuesByKeypath(recentData, currentData) {
  const recentMap = mapDataStructure(recentData);
  const currentMap = mapDataStructure(currentData);

  const recentPaths = new Set([...recentMap.keys()]);
  const currentPaths = new Set([...currentMap.keys()]);

  const collidingPaths = recentPaths.intersection(currentPaths);
  const uniqueRecentPaths = recentPaths.difference(currentPaths);
  const uniqueCurrentPaths = currentPaths.difference(recentPaths);

  return {

    changed: [...collidingPaths.values()]
      .reduce((result, keypath) => {

        const recentValue = recentMap.get(keypath);
        const currentValue = currentMap.get(keypath);

        if (!Object.is(recentValue, currentValue)) {

          result[keypath] = {
            recent: recentValue,
            current: currentValue,
          };
        }
        return result;

      }, {}),

    deleted: [...uniqueRecentPaths.values()]
      .reduce((result, keypath) => {

        result[keypath] = recentMap.get(keypath);
        return result;

      }, {}),

    added: [...uniqueCurrentPaths.values()]
      .reduce((result, keypath) => {

        result[keypath] = currentMap.get(keypath);
        return result;

      }, {}),
  };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -4):

```js
const oldObject = { name: 'John', age: 30, city: 'New York', friends: ['ali', 'qasim'], def: { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 } };

const newObject = { name: 'John', age: 35, city: 'New York', friends: ['ali', 'haider'] };
let oldobj = Object.keys(oldObject)
console.log(oldobj)
let newobj = Object.keys(newObject)
console.log(newobj)
let result = oldobj.filter(x => !newobj.includes(x));

if(result.length> 0){
    console.log(oldObject.def)
}
```

// finding keys in 2 arrays . and checking keys are same in both araays or not

Comment: What makes you think the above provided answer actually provides a generic solution to the OP's original problem which is about nested objects of unknown structure? (btw. the downvote is not mine).